# Package version difference between pip and OS?

Tags: python, pip, six

I have Debian OS and python version 2.7 installed on it. But I have a strange issue about package `six`. I want to use 1.10 version.

I have installed six 1.10 via pip:

```
$ pip list
...
six (1.10.0)
```

But when I run the following script

```
python -c "import six; print(six.__version__)"
```

it says `1.8.0`

The reason is that veriosn installed in OS is different:

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy python-six
python-six:
Installed: 1.8.0-1
Candidate: 1.8.0-1
Version table:
    1.9.0-3~bpo8+1 0
      100 http://172.24.70.103:9999/jessie-backports/ jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
*** 1.8.0-1 0
    500 ftp://172.24.70.103/mirror/jessie-debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://172.24.70.103:9999/jessie-debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**How to force python to use package installed via pip?**

Comment: I am also running Debian Jessie and have `six-1.10.0` installed, but I don't see the behavior you're getting. What is the output of `python -c "from pkg_resources import Environment;print(Environment()['six'])"`?

Comment: where is this package installed with pip? Using the `--user` flag or in `/usr/local`?

Comment: @birryree [six 1.10.0 (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages)]

Comment: @languitar /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Comment: Can you please add the output of: `python -c 'import sys; print("\n".join(sys.path))'` as well as `python -c 'import six; print(six)'`

Comment: @languitar thanks a lot for your help. After executing your last commands I have found that I have 2 python distributions...one in `/usr/lib` and another in `/usr/local/lib`. After replacing six in the first, everything worked

Comment: Maybe answering this question yourself and accepting that answer would then better reflect the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `virtualenv` for this.

```
pip install virtualenv

cd project_folder
virtualenv venv
```

`virtualenv venv` will create a folder in the current directory which will contain the Python executable files, and a copy of the pip library which you can use to install other packages. The name of the virtual environment (in this case, it was venv) can be anything; omitting the name will place the files in the current directory instead.

Set the wished python interpreter

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 venv
```

Activate the environment

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

From now on, any package that you install using pip will be placed in the `venv` folder, isolated from the **global** Python installation.

```
pip install six
```

Now you run code. When you have finished simpliy deactivate `venv`

```
deactivate
```

See also [the original resources](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).

Comment: I almost never recommend `virtualenv`. `virtualenvwrapper` is so much cleaner and, in my opinion, has a much more simple entry point.